# "Each day" or "Every day"

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to use in a poem "we are trading every day for another" instead of we are trading each day for another"?
I know the second option is the grammatically correct one but is the first option ok nonetheless?
Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

*Each* and *every* have similar meanings. Both describe "more than one", but *each* focuses more on **separate** individuals, while *every* focuses on individuals as **members of a group**:

> The contract was signed by *each* director in turn (individuals, one by
>   one). When *every* director had signed the contract, it was sent off (=
>   the whole group).

Note that *each* refers to **two or more things**, *every* to **more than two.**

Speaking of days and your sentence "we are trading every day for another", both *every* and *each* are OK to me. Using *each*, the poet would stress *separate* days, while "every" would make us thinks of days as some "members of a group" (one day - member, a whole sequence of days - group). 
I hope it helps.